# Introspect property types on Django model without 'objects' throwing AttributeError

Tags: python, django, introspection

This sounds like a duplicate, but I absolutely could not find someone with a duplicate of my problem.

My model:

```
class SuperCoolModel(models.Model):
    large = models.ImageField()
    small = models.ImageField()
    blah = some.OtherClass()  # Not a Field type, but is a subclass of ImageFile
```

What I **want** to do is "iterate" (somehow) over the properties on an instance of this model, and do something for properties that are an instance of ImageField.

E.g., here's code **that works**:

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFile
a = SuperCoolModel.objects.get(pk=1)
for attrname in dir(a):
    # Ignore attr names that we obviously don't care about:
    # E.g., anything that starts with an underscore-or-two:
    if attrname.startswith('_'):
        continue
    try:
        if isinstance(getattr(a, attrname), ImageFile):
            field = getattr(a, attrname)
            # Manipulate some stuff, based on the file, 
            # e.g., using `field.path`.
            pass 
    except AttributeError as e:
        # Hopefully this is JUST the 'objects' reference?
        pass
```

In the example above, as it traverses method/property names, when it gets to 'object' it *would* raise:

```
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>   File "/path/to/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 206, in __get__
    raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % type.__name__)
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via SuperCoolModel instances
```

... So I've started watching for the `AttributeError` exception. Alternatively, I could hard-code "objects" in my loop, as I do when checking for underscore names.

**I cannot** use `a._meta.fields`, `a._meta.get_all_field_names()`, etc, because I am also trying to check the type of some arbitrary properties that are **not Fields** but *are* of a certain subclass and/or type.

Am I doing this right, or is there a better way to skip "objects" (and other potential "gotchas") here?

Comment: Is 'objects' doing something it might shouldn't? Perhaps the best answer is to wrap this in a try/except and catch the AttributeError?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your explanation of why you can't use the `_meta` methods: you can use `a._meta.get_all_field_names()` to get a list of the actual fields, then add whatever arbitrary properties you have to the resulting list.

In the upcoming 1.8 release this has been deprecated, you would need to use `[f.name for f in a._meta.get_fields()]`

Note that *none* of the properties will be an instance of ImageField. The instance doesn't have ImageFields (or CharFields, or any fields) as properties; it has actual strings, ints etc, and in the case of images it uses [FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile).

Comment: True, except for the last bit, which I will update code to reflect better. Sorry.

Comment: I updated my code to show an example of: (1) looking for non-Field properties/methods, and (2) showing code that I ended up using, which hopefully better illustrates... (3) why I can't just look at the info available in  `_meta` values.